# What does "(m/f)" mean in job description titles?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it an attempt to specify that both males and females are allowed to apply, as if that wasn't the case everywhere already? I'm mostly seeing this for positions in Germany.

Comment: Male / female. In some countries this is a legal requirement to indicate that the position is open to all genders.

Comment: @MartijnPieters claiming that male and female are the only genders would get you into some real trouble in Sweden :) Even claiming that everyone belongs to a gender will get you into trouble sometimes.

Comment: Also see https://www.quora.com/Why-do-German-job-ads-have-m-f-in-them, [What does H/F, M/F and M/W abbreviation in job titles mean?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/225052), [Question About Job Posting (M/F)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10454)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why are places specifying “(m/f)” in the job title?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59664/why-are-places-specifying-m-f-in-the-job-title/59668#59668) :)

Comment: In Russia it's common to see explicitly stated 'we need a guy' in programming job descriptions too (+ gendered nouns with default male like in german), so I'm generally more likely to apply to jobs that mention `m/f` (which indicates they recognize their developer may not be male). God I want to beautiful Sweden.

Comment: Okey, technically some job titles are gendered in Swedish, but we don't change the gender of the words based on the gender of the person performing them. Nurses are female, teachers are male, but most job titles (doctors, principals, developers, drivers, designers, farmers, ...) are not gendered at all. I even had to think for a while to come up with one of each gender.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this hasn't been asked on a meta before. Lots of people have wondered about this. (BTW - I'm Australian (the country with kangaroos), not German)

Comment: (Teacher actually used to be gendered in Swedish like in German, but over the last 5-10 years we seem to have stopped using the female version)

Comment: Germany has jobs that are not open to both sexes? wtf ^^

Comment: I was under the impression that it stands for frontend/middleware/database till now. And then I would wonder why the description does not match the job title :-)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

German is one of those languages in which nouns have a gender, so many job titles implicitly have a gender attached to them. Whether that historically means anything or not in regard to actual biological genders is a different discussion. A job title of *"Softwareentwickler"* is grammatically male; to make it clear that women are equally invited to apply, this is either written as *"Softwareentwickler/-in"*, or by adding an *"(m/f)"*. Whether or not this is always useful for all job titles, e.g. "developer", is yet another discussion to be had, but that's the prevalent politically-correct climate in Germany (and I suppose other countries) at the moment.

Comment: Ah, of course. I reacted because this would be a very politically *incorrect* thing to do in Sweden (where nouns are not gendered). I would be really hesitant about working somewhere where the fact that women are allowed to apply has to be explicitly stated in the job description.

Comment: @Filip ha, that's funny that something that is the height of inclusiveness in one country reads like "... and we now even allow women!" in another culture.  We probably won't be able to eliminate this cultural artifact completely with German job ads - there *might* even be legal repercussions if you omit this in Germany. It could at least be a beneficial factor in a discrimination suit, if not grounds in itself. That should not apply to English language ads for obvious reasons - but weirder things have happened in German courts...

Comment: @Pekka웃 and it's only a 70km boat ride between the two countries! We practically share a border!

Comment: So, in Germany, gender is still a binary concept? This doesn't seem especially "progressive" or "politically correct" to me.

Comment: @Cody The German language has and had for a long time *three* grammatical genders! You were saying…? :-P

Comment: I don't mean grammatical gender, of course. My understanding from college linguistics courses is that this has *nothing* to do historically with actual biological genders. It certainly doesn't seem to in the German language, as Mark Twain famously satirized to the English-speaking world.

Comment: @CodyGray indeed! The moon is male; the sun female; the tree male, etc. That's a fundamental of the language though, something I think not even the most progressive folks would be comfortable with touching (except in Academia.)

Comment: @Cody Of course I was teasing… But again, the issue is that grammatical and biological gender is somewhat linked in German, more so than in English. If you wanted to include all LGBTQ+ designations, you'd probably need to invent 5+ more grammatical genders; or you'd have to redo the entire system to decouple biological and grammatical gender. And that while people are already getting riled up that explicitly having to state *two* genders is already cumbersome. Just because it's expressed in writing one way doesn't mean people aren't already acting progressively. It's not the same as the US.

Comment: And the girl is neuter.  I did not enjoy having to learn that :)

Comment: From now on, I'm not a programmer.  I'm a 'twickler.

Comment: They do the same in Spanish by using the @ symbol to signify the 'o' for masculine and 'a' for feminine.

Comment: @Brandon Wow, that's fascinating. So it would say "Developer @"? That's *gotta* be confusing sometimes.

Comment: Well, developer isn't a great example Spanish because it can be either gender even though it is a masculine noun . But using it as an example 
desarrollador@ where the last letter would be o or a to denote gender.

Comment: @Brandon Ah, I see, that makes sense. Looks like people could have some fun with their email addresses this way too.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen That's interesting. But in your example, it should either be an "a" or a blank. There's no desarrolladoro, eh.

Comment: @Frank I did say it wasn't a great example :)

Comment: I think empleado is a better example. "Looking for employee". "Se busca emplead@" or "worker" = tradajador@

Comment: @Will You've caused me to update my profile for the first time in years! http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze?tab=profile

Comment: HAH!  Wonderful!  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will?tab=profile

Comment: In Germany, is more than politically correct. It is by law stablished.